# Rules for Active directory user name string

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory

I have googled but not able to find a proper set of restriction in user name in active directory setting.

Please help me in telling what are the special char which are not allowed in Active directory user name settings.

Is single quote (') is allowed or not.

Answer (score 16):

Here are the documents you're looking for:

[User and Group Accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726984.aspx)
[Computers, Domains, Sites, and OUs](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264)

Basically, user names can contain a single quote character, but computer names cannot.

These documents are very old, but if that's the way it was in Win2000, you can bet current versions retain the limitations for backward compatibility.

Comment: I didn't found the rule for a user name in the links you have given. Can you specify which one on the links shows the user name rules.

Comment: Under rules for logon names near the top, it states this:  

"Logon names can't contain certain characters. Invalid characters are

" / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >

Logon names can contain all other special characters, including spaces, periods, dashes, and underscores. But it's generally not a good idea to use spaces in account names."

Comment: Ok.. Logon Name specifies the user name..

Comment: "all other special characters"? In which charset? Can emoji or control chars be used?

Comment: @brianary [Seeming as you can use emojis for Windows network computer names](https://windowsreport.com/pc-name-emoji/), so I assume it would work for login usernames too...

Answer (score 14):

[RFC 2253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2253.txt)

> The names of security principal objects can contain all Unicode
>   characters except the special LDAP characters defined in RFC 2253.
>   This list of special characters includes: a leading space; a trailing
>   space; and any of the following characters: # , + " \ < > ;

[Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/bb726984(v=technet.10))

> Logon names can't contain certain characters. Invalid characters are
>
> " / \ [ ] : ; | = , + * ? < >
>
> Logon names can contain all other special characters, including spaces, periods, dashes, and underscores. But it's generally not a good idea to use spaces in account names.

[Microsoft on sAMAccountName](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11216.active-directory-requirements-for-creating-objects.aspx#Note_Regarding_the_quot_quot_Character_in_sAMAccountName)

> - All printable characters are allowed in sAMAccountName values except    the following: " [ ] : ; | = + * ? < > / \ ,
> - The period character, ".", is allowed, but it cannot be the final character in the sAMAccountName.
> - Non-printable characters are not allowed. This includes all characters with ASCII codes less than 32 decimal (20 hex). Also the
>     Delete control character, with ASCII code 127 decimal (7F hex) is not 
>     allowed.
> - Active Directory Users and Computers (ADUC) will not allow you to assign a value to the sAMAccountName attribute that includes the "@"
>     character. However, you can do this in code. For example, the
>     Set-ADUser cmdlet allows you to assign a sAMAccountName with this
>     character. But you cannot logon to a domain using a sAMAccountName
>     that includes the "@" character. If a user has a sAMAccountName with
>     this character, they must logon using their userPrincipalName (UPN).
>     See the note below.
> - The schema allows 256 characters in sAMAccountName values. However, the system limits sAMAccountName to 20 characters for user objects
>     and 16 characters for computer objects.